# Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' using password: YES in springboot

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

> I try to solve this problme  last9 hour but still i am not able to
>   solve the issue,i try everything,change my sqlversion but still same
>   error Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
>   i use wamp server for mysql database
>
> Caused by: com.mysql.cj.exceptions.CJException: Access denied for
>   user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
>         at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_241]
>         at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_241]
>         at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown
>   Source) ~[na:1.8.0_241]
>         at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_241]
>         at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:61)
>   ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.19.jar:8.0.19]
>         at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:105)
>   ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.19.jar:8.0.19]
>         at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:151)
>   ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.19.jar:8.0.19]
>         at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:129)
>   ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.19.jar:8.0.19]
>         at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeProtocol.checkErrorMessage(NativeProtocol.java:787)
>   ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.19.jar:8.0.19]
>         at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeProtocol.checkErrorMessage(NativeProtocol.java:712)
>   ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.19.jar:8.0.19]
>         at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeProtocol.checkErrorMessage(NativeProtocol.java:680)
>   ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.19.jar:8.0.19]
>         at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeProtocol.checkErrorMessage(NativeProtocol.java:128)
>   ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.19.jar:8.0.19]
>         at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeAuthenticationProvider.proceedHandshakeWithPluggableAuthentication(NativeAuthenticationProvider.java:540)
>   ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.19.jar:8.0.19]
>         at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeAuthenticationProvider.connect(NativeAuthenticationProvider.java:202)
>   ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.19.jar:8.0.19]
>         at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeProtocol.connect(NativeProtocol.java:1340)
>   ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.19.jar:8.0.19]
>         at com.mysql.cj.NativeSession.connect(NativeSession.java:157) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.19.jar:8.0.19]
>         at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectWithRetries(ConnectionImpl.java:850)
>   ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.19.jar:8.0.19]
>         ... 54 common frames omitted
>
> ```
> 2020-03-25 13:19:21.603  WARN 10824 --- [  restartedMain] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 0, SQLState:
> ```
>
> 08001
>       2020-03-25 13:19:21.604 ERROR 10824 --- [  restartedMain] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : Could not create connection
>   to database server. Attempted reconnect 3 times. Giving up.
>       2020-03-25 13:19:21.639  WARN 10824 --- [  restartedMain] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered
>   during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path
>   resource
>   [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]:
>   Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is
>   javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default]
>   Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is
>   org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Unable to open JDBC
>   Connection for DDL execution
>       2020-03-25 13:19:21.677  INFO 10824 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
>       2020-03-25 13:19:21.708  INFO 10824 --- [  restartedMain] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener :
>
> ```
> Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
> 2020-03-25 13:19:21.711 ERROR 10824 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed
>
> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path
> ```
>
> resource
>   [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]:
>   Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is
>   javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default]
>   Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is
>   org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Unable to open JDBC
>   Connection for DDL execution
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1796)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:595)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1108)
>   ~[spring-context-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:868)
>   ~[spring-context-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550)
>   ~[spring-context-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:141)
>   ~[spring-boot-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:747)
>   [spring-boot-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397)
>   [spring-boot-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315)
>   [spring-boot-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226)
>   [spring-boot-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1215)
>   [spring-boot-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
>         at com.mysqljpa.MysqlrestApi.MysqlrestApiApplication.main(MysqlrestApiApplication.java:10)
>   [classes/:na]
>         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_241]
>         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_241]
>         at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_241]
>         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_241]
>         at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49)
>   [spring-boot-devtools-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
>       Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory;
>   nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException:
>   Unable to open JDBC Connection for DDL execution
>         at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:403)
>   ~[spring-orm-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:378)
>   ~[spring-orm-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341)
>   ~[spring-orm-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1855)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1792)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
>         ... 21 common frames omitted
>       Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Unable to open JDBC Connection for DDL execution
>         at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.convert(SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.java:48)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
>         at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:42)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
>         at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:113)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
>         at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:99)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
>         at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.DdlTransactionIsolatorNonJtaImpl.getIsolatedConnection(DdlTransactionIsolatorNonJtaImpl.java:69)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
>         at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.ImprovedExtractionContextImpl.getJdbcConnection(ImprovedExtractionContextImpl.java:60)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
>         at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.ImprovedExtractionContextImpl.getJdbcDatabaseMetaData(ImprovedExtractionContextImpl.java:67)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
>         at org.hibernate.tool.schema.extract.internal.InformationExtractorJdbcDatabaseMetaDataImpl.getTables(InformationExtractorJdbcDatabaseMetaDataImpl.java:333)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
>         at org.hibernate.tool.schema.extract.internal.DatabaseInformationImpl.getTablesInformation(DatabaseInformationImpl.java:120)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
>         at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.GroupedSchemaMigratorImpl.performTablesMigration(GroupedSchemaMigratorImpl.java:65)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
>         at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.performMigration(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:207)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
>         at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.doMigration(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:114)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
>         at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.performDatabaseAction(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:184)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
>         at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.process(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:73)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
>         at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.(SessionFactoryImpl.java:314)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
>         at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:468)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
>         at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1237)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
>         at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:58)
>   ~[spring-orm-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365)
>   ~[spring-orm-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:391)
>   ~[spring-orm-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
>         ... 25 common frames omitted
>       Caused by: java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: Could not create connection to database server. Attempted reconnect 3 times.
>   Giving up.
>         at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:110)
>   ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.19.jar:8.0.19]
>         at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:97)
>   ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.19.jar:8.0.19]
>         at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:89)
>   ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.19.jar:8.0.19]
>         at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:63)
>   ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.19.jar:8.0.19]
>         at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:73)
>   ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.19.jar:8.0.19]
>         at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectWithRetries(ConnectionImpl.java:906)
>   ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.19.jar:8.0.19]
>         at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:831)
>   ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.19.jar:8.0.19]
>         at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.(ConnectionImpl.java:456)
>   ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.19.jar:8.0.19]
>         at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:246)
>   ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.19.jar:8.0.19]
>         at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:197)
>   ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.19.jar:8.0.19]
>         at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:138)
>   ~[HikariCP-3.4.2.jar:na]
>         at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:354)
>   ~[HikariCP-3.4.2.jar:na]
>         at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:202)
>   ~[HikariCP-3.4.2.jar:na]
>         at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:473)
>   ~[HikariCP-3.4.2.jar:na]
>         at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:554)
>   ~[HikariCP-3.4.2.jar:na]
>         at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.(HikariPool.java:115) ~[HikariCP-3.4.2.jar:na]
>         at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:112)
>   ~[HikariCP-3.4.2.jar:na]
>         at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:122)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
>         at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator$ConnectionProviderJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:180)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
>         at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.DdlTransactionIsolatorNonJtaImpl.getIsolatedConnection(DdlTransactionIsolatorNonJtaImpl.java:43)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
>         ... 40 common frames omitted
>       Caused by: com.mysql.cj.exceptions.CJException: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
>         at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_241]
>         at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_241]
>         at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown
>   Source) ~[na:1.8.0_241]
>         at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_241]
>         at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:61)
>   ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.19.jar:8.0.19]
>         at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:105)
>   ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.19.jar:8.0.19]
>         at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:151)
>   ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.19.jar:8.0.19]
>         at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:129)
>   ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.19.jar:8.0.19]
>         at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeProtocol.checkErrorMessage(NativeProtocol.java:787)
>   ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.19.jar:8.0.19]
>         at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeProtocol.checkErrorMessage(NativeProtocol.java:712)
>   ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.19.jar:8.0.19]
>         at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeProtocol.checkErrorMessage(NativeProtocol.java:680)
>   ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.19.jar:8.0.19]
>         at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeProtocol.checkErrorMessage(NativeProtocol.java:128)
>   ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.19.jar:8.0.19]
>         at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeAuthenticationProvider.proceedHandshakeWithPluggableAuthentication(NativeAuthenticationProvider.java:540)
>   ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.19.jar:8.0.19]
>         at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeAuthenticationProvider.connect(NativeAuthenticationProvider.java:202)
>   ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.19.jar:8.0.19]
>         at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeProtocol.connect(NativeProtocol.java:1340)
>   ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.19.jar:8.0.19]
>         at com.mysql.cj.NativeSession.connect(NativeSession.java:157) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.19.jar:8.0.19]
>         at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectWithRetries(ConnectionImpl.java:850)
>   ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.19.jar:8.0.19]
>         ... 54 common frames omitted
>
> Application.prop

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/bwlhai
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=root
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update

> MySqlRestApi.java
package com.mysqljpa.MysqlrestApi;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class MysqlrestApiApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MysqlrestApiApplication.class, args);
    }

}

> pom.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.5.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.mysqljpa</groupId>
    <artifactId>MysqlrestApi</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>MysqlrestApi</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.19</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>

> Book.java
package com.mysqljpa.MysqlrestApi.model;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotBlank;

@Entity
@Table(name="books")
public class Book {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
    @NotBlank
    private String name;
    @NotBlank
    private String author;
    @NotBlank
    private String isbn;
    public Book() {
        super();
    }
    public Book(Long id, String name, String author, String isbn) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.author = author;
        this.isbn = isbn;
    }
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getAuthor() {
        return author;
    }
    public void setAuthor(String author) {
        this.author = author;
    }
    public String getIsbn() {
        return isbn;
    }
    public void setIsbn(String isbn) {
        this.isbn = isbn;
    }



}

> BookRepo.java
package com.mysqljpa.MysqlrestApi.Repository;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import com.mysqljpa.MysqlrestApi.model.Book;
@Repository

public interface BookRepo extends JpaRepository<Book, Long> {

}

> BookController
package com.mysqljpa.Controller;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.mysqljpa.MysqlrestApi.Repository.BookRepo;
import com.mysqljpa.MysqlrestApi.model.Book;

@RestController
public class BookController {
    @Autowired
    BookRepo bkr;
    //Get All book
    @GetMapping("/books")
    public List<Book> getAllNotes(){
        return bkr.findAll();

    }   
    //Create a note



}

> BookException
package com.restapi.Exception;

public class BookNotFoundExc extends Exception {
   private long book_id;

public BookNotFoundExc(long book_id) {
    super(String.format("Book is not found with id : '%s'", book_id));
}



}
```

Comment: If you go to localhost/phpmyadmin, do you have to fill in a password? Because I don't, and it says you filled in a password. Maybe try to leave it blank?

Comment: when live blank password section it shows me "Unknown database "mydatabsaename""

Comment: Then database does not exist. What database name did you specify in your app? And when you login on your phpmyadmin, what databases do you see there?

Comment: I see there two database MariaDb,MySQL